# Why http request send twice from client to server ( OPTION and POST )

Tags: html, http, post, angular, http-options-method

When I click the submit button, http request send twice from client to server. 
first one is OPTIONS and other one is POST method.

**login form**
[image]

**HTTP Requests** 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

> Preflighted requests
>
> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first
>   send an **HTTP OPTIONS** request header to the resource on the other
>   domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to
>   send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may
>   have implications to user data. In particular, a request is
>   preflighted if:
>
> It uses methods other than GET or POST. Also, if POST is used to send
>   request data with a Content-Type other than
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain,
>   e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using
>   application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted. It sets
>   custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header such as
>   X-PINGOTHER)